# how to a make label message disable after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with two text boxes. Once I enter the data and click the save button, I get a message in label: indicating that it saved successfully.

Then i am in the same form again, but when I click on the save button, I get a message telling me that it cannot be blank "as textbox value is empty this time" from the required field validator.

But I am still showing the message "data saved successfully," which should not happen.
 is there any way   can   after  showing the message: data  saved  sucessfully. after 10 seconds. i  can    hide the label.   are  clear the value in tha label. sothati snt show the message
How do I solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout("function_to_hide_label()", time_in_milliseconds);
```

Time is "after how much time the function should be called".

**Edit:**

```
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
       $('#lblsuccess').show();
       setTimeout(function(){  $('#lblsuccess').hide(); }, 10000); 
});
```

Something like this should probably work, I didn't test it though.

Comment: my  label id:lblsuccess , my button  id: btnSave  so  would  you  plz  give the  entire  coding how  to  to  do it

Comment: Just a little note, `setTimeout("function_to_hide_label()", time_in_milliseconds);` can be written as `setTimeout(function_to_hide_label, time_in_milliseconds);`, no implicit eval, just a plain old function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a timeout in Javascript or maybe the [timer plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers) from jQuery. This will allow you to create a function that removes the message after a period of time. I haven't used the timer plugin myself but it seems pretty stable.

```
$("#save-button").click(function() {
        //code to save etc
        $("your label").oneTime(10000, "hide", function() {
               $("Your Label").hide();
         });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the jQuery [timer plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers). You can do something like this:

```
$('#your-label').oneTime(10000, function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: hi. 
how  to call this  function . on  button click  event  should i call this  functinor    how  should i  be calling this  function

Answer (score -1):

You should change your validation function to clear the message when it runs. This way when the user tries to resubmit the form, the data message goes away at that time. Making it disappear after 10 seconds will feel strange if the form is resubmitted within 10 seconds.